# Excel VBA code to filter specific columns and delete the data from other columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter data from Column H in my excel sheet based on the name "IBM_Software" and delete the hierarchy data in Column J of same sheet. Below is the code that i used, but its not working the way i want and it deletes the row on top too which is bad.

```
Sub Delete_Rows_Based_On_Value()
'Apply a filter to a Range and delete visible rows
'Source: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/delete-rows-cell-values/


'''
Dim ws As Worksheet

  'Set reference to the sheet in the workbook.
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BDDASHBTEMPLATEFYTD21BILLING3")
  ws.Activate 'not required but allows user to view sheet if warning message appears

  'Clear any existing filters
  On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

  '1. Apply Filter
  ws.Range("A:P").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="IBM_Software"

  '2. Delete Rows
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Sheets("BDDASHBTEMPLATEFYTD21BILLING3").AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Delete xlShiftUp
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True


  '3. Clear Filter
  On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution not working probably means you are getting an error.  It is also unlikely that you have data in every row on the sheet.  You can't offset one row if you are using every row.  I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to find the last row (LR).  This solution deletes only the filtered rows, your solution would delete all.

```
ws.Range("A1:P" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="IBM_Software"
ws.Range("A1.P" & LR).Offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, But in my case i want to delete only specific column J after filtering the column data from H. Unfortunately your code is not correct in this case

Comment: That was not your original statement nor what your code represents.  You cannot delete data in Column J without deleting the entire column.  If you want to clear the data, you will need `ClearContents`.  You will still want to use the `SpecialCells` to only clear the filtered data.

Comment: Yes sir i applied 
{
 
 
 
 Worksheets("BDDASHBTEMPLATEFYTD21BILLING3").Columns(10).ClearContents

Comment: To only clear the filtered data you would want `ws.Range("J2:J" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents`.  This skips the header.